# SSH подключение к Android девайсу

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Здравствуйте, возможно ли разработать приложение для Android которое бы создавало сессию ssh и к которой можно было подключиться по средствам ip и port.

Comment: Наличие соответствующих [приложений](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sshserver) в Play Market'е как бы намекает, что это возможно.

Comment: Насколько я понял, это приложение создает SSH сервер, к которому можно подключиться только из локальной сети, мне же нужно чтобы можно было подключиться по внешнему ip.

Comment: Если у устройства есть "белый" IP, то что мешает к нему подключиться извне? Если нет, то каким образом Вы планируете к нему подключаться (не суть важно, по SSH ли, или любым другим способом)?

Comment: Я уверен что там не так все просто, нужно пробросить порты как я понимаю, вот и я задал вопрос, может кто-то уже реализовывал данную функцию.